# Vostro 3300 Driver, a known issue with no solution?

Tags: networking, drivers, dell, broadcom, dell-vostro

Thank you for your help with my [question previously](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1218274/wifi-driver-for-vostro-3300) however the [solution](https://askubuntu.com/questions/55868/installing-broadcom-wireless-drivers) has not worked for me.

Steps taken based on solution (apologies my pastebin link expired so i do not have the terminal output any longer):

- Complete reinstallation of Ubuntu Desktop 18.04.4
- Update and update pciids
- 14e4:4727 rev 01  Special Case #1: so i installed linux-firmware
- This did not work so based on the important note I did:

  > ```
  >  sudo apt install firmware-b43-installer
  > ```
- This did not work so I then did:

  > ```
  >  sudo modprobe -r b43
  >  sudo modprobe b43    
  >  sudo rfkill unblock all
  > ```

This did not work so I searched again for **4727 rev 01** which led me to [this solution](https://askubuntu.com/a/1152706).

```
msk@delete:~$ sudo gedit /etc/default/crda

** (gedit:3055): WARNING **: 21:34:13.448: Set document metadata failed: Setting attribute metadata::gedit-spell-language not supported

** (gedit:3055): WARNING **: 21:34:13.448: Set document metadata failed: Setting attribute metadata::gedit-encoding not supported

** (gedit:3055): WARNING **: 21:34:13.990: Set document metadata failed: Setting attribute metadata::gedit-spell-language not supported

** (gedit:3055): WARNING **: 21:34:13.990: Set document metadata failed: Setting attribute metadata::gedit-encoding not supported

** (gedit:3055): WARNING **: 21:34:14.148: Set document metadata failed: Setting attribute metadata::gedit-spell-language not supported

** (gedit:3055): WARNING **: 21:34:14.149: Set document metadata failed: Setting attribute metadata::gedit-encoding not supported

** (gedit:3055): WARNING **: 21:34:15.650: Set document metadata failed: Setting attribute metadata::gedit-position not supported
```

This brought up a document which i edited as suggested.

After that didn't work I came to the [documentation here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/Driver/bcm43xx#Top). I believe my case would fall under the Known Issues section. Namely:

> Known Issues
>
> - LP#1010931 14e4:4727 [Dell Vostro 3555] Broadcom BCM4313 5GHz doesn't work but 2.4GHz does
>
>   The root cause is the card only transmits/receives on the single-band 2.4GHz only, so it would never broadcast at 5GHz

Am I correct in thinking that this might not be a resolveable issue?

I do not think this is a hardware issue as for about a year prior to me installing linux onto this laptop I could connect to the wifi fine.

Other info:

```
msk@delete:~$ lspci -nn -d 14e4:
12:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries BCM4313 802.11bgn Wireless Network Adapter [14e4:4727] (rev 01)
```

Comment: Please see comment #38 here: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1010931 Since it is a hardware limitation, it cannot be fixed by any changes in Ubuntu or, more broadly, Linux.

Comment: Thank you for all your help through this chili555. My only follow up question would be, is this not a software issue? Given that this laptop was able to connect a matter of weeks ago (when using windows) and for a year prior to this, is this not a software issue with no known fix for Linux, as opposed to a hardware issue?

Comment: Everything I have been able to read, including the linked bug report, suggests that it is a single-band device and not capable of 5 gHz connection. In any event, it is an older device and I doubt that Broadcom, who provide the proprietary driver, are likely to address this in any way. Please check what Broadcom's own README says: https://docs.broadcom.com/docs-and-downloads/docs/linux_sta/README_6.30.223.271.txt